# Edit and delete list by button + change in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have an list and i want to edit content of it by clicking a button then save it to localstorage and by clicking another button i want to delete it and also change local storage,
My list looks like this: [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUQsp.png)

```
    function editButton(){
        event.target.parentElement.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);

    }
    function deleteButton(){
        event.target.parentElement.remove();
    }
```

Delete button works pretty good it deletes the li item on the scene not in local storage.
Edit button makes whole li editable, including buttons but I want to change that.

My list after clicking edit button looks like this:
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrWdV.png)

And there is how i store my items in local storage and how im getting them:

```
    function store(item){
        let items = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('myItems'));
        items = items === null ? [] : items;
        console.log(items);
        window.localStorage.setItem('myItems',JSON.stringify([...items,item]));
    }
    function getValues(){
        let list = document.querySelector('ul');
        let storedValues = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('myItems'));
        if(!storedValues){
            list.innerHTML = '';
        }
        else {
            storedValues.forEach(val =>{
                if(val){
                    list.innerHTML += '<li>'+'<a>' + val.name + " "+val.date +'</a>'+'<button onclick="editButton()">'+"Edytuj"+'</button>'+'<button onclick="deleteButton()">'+"Usuń"+'</button>'+'</li>';
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: if `edit`, `delete` button is in `li`, you should use another div so that it can contain all children of `li` except the buttons. And your delete/edit function doesn't have localstorage  code implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i did some changes and removing works now good

```
    function deleteButton(){
        event.target.parentElement.remove();
        let a = event.target.parentElement.innerText;
        let word = a.split(' ');
        let item = new Array();
        let i = 0;
        let storedValues = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('myItems'));
        window.localStorage.removeItem('myItems');
        storedValues.forEach(val =>{
            if(val.name === word[0]){
                console.log(val.name);
            }
            else {
                item[i] = new storage1(val.name,val.date);
                i++;
            }
        });
        window.localStorage.setItem('myItems',JSON.stringify(item));
        storedValues = [];
    }
```

But i still get into this editing list, when i change `<li><a></a><button>...` to `<li><a><div></div></a>...` it doesnt work, is there any way to edit only text?
Or maybe just stop inputing text after an enter